# AWS EBS ERROR: Source bundle is empty or exceeds maximum allowed size: 524288000

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am getting this error on the Terminal command line when I go to deploy my code to Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk.

How do i fix this issue?

Comment: Error is very explicit, what file size do you have for your sources?

Comment: @sap1ens - it's definitely less than 524 MB. I'm deploying a Node/Express/Angular app - it's about 150 MB in size (node_modules is what's bloating the file size).

Answer (score 2):

eb tool is creating archive with name of a --label command line argument on s3 storage.

May be eb uploaded bad archive with same name...

Make sure your local git repository contains good files.
Then try to use different --label argument.
For example: eb deploy --label test1

Comment: 5 years later, this is still a good answer. Thanks @loopzilla!